# Can I avoid using cursor in this recursive lookup scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor, common-table-expression

I have a Table called Item. The design is like:

```
ItemTable[
ItemID int,
ItemName varchar(50),
ParentItemId int ]
```

What I want is to find all the items that have an ancestor id and do some operation (e.g. delete, update).

Say I have six items,

```
For Item 1, the parentItemId is null, 
for Item 2, the parentId is 1,
for Item 3, the parentId is 1
Item 4, parent id 2, 
item 5, parent id 2, 
item 6, parent id 4
```

I want to find all items that has an ancestor id 2. So should be 4,5, and 6.

In sql world, I can do it in a cursor. But wondering if it is something can be done using a clever CTE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursive CTE:

```
;WITH cte(ItemID, ItemName,ParentItemId) AS (
   SELECT ItemID, ItemName, ParentItemId
   FROM #ItemTable
   WHERE ParentItemId IS NOT NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT i.ItemID, i.ItemName, t.ParentItemId
   FROM cte t 
   JOIN #ItemTable i 
     ON t.ItemID = i.ParentItemId
), cte2 AS                -- filter records with Ancestor = 2
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM cte
  WHERE ParentItemId = 2
)
UPDATE #ItemTable          -- UPDATE/DELETE operation
SET ItemName = CONCAT('Updated Name: ', i1.ItemName)
FROM #ItemTable i1
JOIN cte2 c2
  ON i1.ItemID = c2.ItemId;

SELECT *
FROM #ItemTable;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398861)**</kbd>